# Exception on start of a simple application

Tags: android, sockets

I am newbie in Android. I have created a simlpe application with just LoginDialog and I get the following error on trying to run the application.

```
[2011-03-31 15:08:00 - ddmlib]An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:574)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:420)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:854)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:822)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:781)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:649)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:42)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:577)
```

When I start emulator, I get a message "Cannto find internet", Internet is on then why it can't find internet. And the above errors, I am not using any such thing in the app. Just simple a LoginDialog with 2 edittext & 2 buttons. On Ok, checks edittext values and displays them and closes the dialog. On cancel button, just closes the dialog.

In my Activity class onCreate, I add these 3 lines :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ld = new LoginDialog(this.getApplicationContext());
    ld.show();
}
```

LoginDialog extends Dialog and has 2 edittext and 2 buttons. I am using android 3.0 and 5444 emulator.

### Updated CODE :

Manifest :

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER"></uses-permission>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER"></uses-permission>
    <activity android:name=".StartUltimate"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

I just added 2 uses-permission, rest all is genrated code. I didn't know which more permissions to add. 
In my Activity class :
    static final int DIALOG_LOGIN_ID = 0;
    static final int DIALOG_ABOUT_ID = 1;

```
    protected void OnResume() {
    super.onResume();
    showDialog(R.id.user_pws_root, null);  // DIALOG_LOGIN_ID - tried with this also

    //this.finish();
}


protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog = null;
    switch(id) {
        case DIALOG_LOGIN_ID:
            // Create an instance of the login dialog
            ld = new LoginDialog(this.getApplicationContext());
            dialog = ld;
            //return ld;
            break;
        case DIALOG_ABOUT_ID:
            dialog = null;
            break;
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

showDialog will call onCreateDialog passing the id. createDialog will instantiate it and should be shown. But it doesn't.

LoginDaialog code :

```
public class LoginDialog extends Dialog {
private Button btn_ok, btn_cancel;
private EditText txt_username, txt_password;

public LoginDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    this.setContentView(R.layout.user_pass_dialog);
    this.setTitle("Login to Ultimate VPN");
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);

    btn_ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.user_pwd_btn_ok);
    btn_cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.user_pwd_btn_cancel);

    txt_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_pwd_username);
    txt_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_pwd_password);

    txt_username.setFocusable(true);
    btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String username = LoginDialog.this.txt_username.getText().toString();
            String password = LoginDialog.this.txt_password.getText().toString();

            if (username.length() > 0 && password.length() > 0)
                Toast.makeText(LoginDialog.this.getContext(), "You have entered : " + username + ", " + password, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            LoginDialog.this.dismiss();
        }
    });

    btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LoginDialog.this.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

}

With this code all I see is a black screen with android icon and application name on top of the screen. 
All I want to do is on start of the application, open logindialog. Ask user to enter details and on dismiss of loginDialog the activity should be notified. That's it. I am also referring the API and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ShowingADialog and trying to figure out, but just cna't do it. And that exception in Console window keeps on coming. I can't even find any such pure example on net which I can use as reference. Where am I going wrong and how to rectify it ?

Kindly help me know why I am facing this error. What's the problem with the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have the solution. Have you set the appropriate permissions in the AndroidManifest? Not doing so may result in an exception as you described.

Comment: Well, I haven't added any permission. Can you let me know what type of permission(s) to be added. I have no clue about this as didn't find in any tutorial, so fat. Thanks.

Comment: I have added the code and the permission that I have set. Don't know which more to set. Kindly have a look at it and try to help me out.

Comment: It's hard to see what to make of it, but I found a couple of other ways to do the login: 1) Let the first Activity be the login-screen. When the user has entered information and pressed "login", you check the credentials and start a new Activity. A somewhat complete tutorial can be found here: http://www.anddev.org/building_a_generic_login_page-t98.html  .. Alternative 2: Check out the following which is "official" code and seems to what you are thinking of: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html

Comment: Thanks a lot pecka85. Your second option is some kind of what I wanted to do next i.e. Authenticating login details with server. By the way, I created another AVD for API level 10 i.e. SDK 2.3.3 nd in that my application runs smoothly without any exception. Is this a bug in 3.0 ? As I don't have any such code that shouldn't run on 3.0. Anyways, Thanks once again. If am stuck up will come back again with a new thread. Hope will receive help with that also.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like an error from your code.
Have you tried to use another avd? I would also try to comment the LoginDialog lines so that you just should get a blank screen when the application is started.

Does the app start or do you only get the "no internet" message? What do you see in your LogCat?

Comment: I use it with Eclipse and how can I have more than 1 AVD ? I removed the "ld =  & ld.show" to "OnResume" and I see a blank screen. No error message, but the above message are still seen in Console windw of Eclipse. I noted such exceptions in Console window if am late in taking any actions - kind of time out. When have added the lines in OnResume, I should see the dialog once the blank screen on the app comes. But it doesn't come. Why so. How to call a Dialog class & make it visible ? "No Internet" comes on right left bottom nex to battery and range icons.

Comment: Use the avd manager in eclipse, you can create as much avd as you want, @pecka85 answer is going in the same direction...

Comment: Why I can't see the LoginDialog ? That should be visible after adding the code to OnResume() of the Activity ?      super.onResume();
        ld = new LoginDialog(this.getApplicationContext());
        ld.show();      ????????????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: On start of emulator yet the above exception is thrown and visible in Console window.

Comment: WarrenFaith, I created another AVD of version 10 SDK 2.3.3 and in that my application runs smoothly without any exception. If I would have doen this earlier wouldn't have wasted so much of time. But anyways, got new resources from this researching. Thanks alot. Hope to get help from you in future also.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's not your application that's the problem, rather the emulator. I guess you'll get the same error when you try to start the emulator without your application. You can start the emulator manually by going to the "Android SDK and AVD Manager" and choose start.

If it do start fine, try to open the pre-installed app "Internet". Are you able to surfe the web through this?

Comment: Seems that @WarrenFaith beat me to it.. :)

Comment: Yes I just tested and am able to surf the net. On bottom right I was seeing "No Internet" next to battery & range icons. But can surf the net, so I guess can just ignore the no internet message.

Comment: Yes, you can probably ignore it. As for the still-present problem: this link might help you: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html